# image processing in python using open cv

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 
fc=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_fontalface_default.xml")

img=cv2.imread('dp.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces= fc.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitkey()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9ba3354eb85a> in <module>
      3 
      4 img=cv2.imread('dp.jpg')
----> 5 gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      6 
      7 faces= fc.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-rwld3ghi\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is in the right place? cv2 sometimes quietly doesn't read the image but returns None and then gives an error the first time you try to operate on it.  Look at the value of img in a debugger.

Comment: Please phrase your question and emphasize what you have tried yourself to fix it. It appears a bit rude if you just post your code (it is not even reproducible) and the resulting error message

Answer (score 1):

Below are the possible reasons for the error

- Give full path for your `haar cascade` file
- Give the full path for your `image`. Check whether `cv2` as correctly read your image by using `print(img)` , if it returns `None` then the path specified by you is **incorrect**. Correct your path and try printing the image, if an `array` shows up then you are well to go as your image is now read successfully

Comment: Please add code inside it will be better for other people to understand. Thanks @Akshat